# Limit of a continued fraction

Tags: integration, continued-fractions

Given the continued fraction:
$$f(x,N)=\left[2,3,4,...N,x\right]$$
$$f(x,N)=\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{...+\cfrac{1}{x}}}}}$$
is it possible to find an expression for the integral:
$$g(x,N)=\int f(x,N)dx$$
as function of $N$ and $x$?
Thanks.

Comment: For any given $N$, $f$ is just a rational function. If there is a general closed form for general $N$, I do not know.

Comment: The recurrence relation as obtained in theorem 1 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems) has (according to Mathematica) solutions involving Bessel functions. But in principle (if you don't mind not having elementary formulae for $h_n$ and $k_n$) you just obtain a rational function, which you can integrate using your favourite technique.

Comment: @Riccardo: I obtained further simplifications and references that could interest you. The final simplifation may probably be obtained using the Wronskien formulas from [A & S page $360$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_360.htm) around $9.1.15$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Let's observe that for : 
$$0+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{...+\cfrac{1}{N+\cfrac{1}x}}}}}}$$
the $n$-th convergent is known (from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstant.html), see too OEIS [A052119](http://oeis.org/A052119)) using [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) :

\begin{align}
A_n&=\frac{I_n(-2)K_1(2)-I_1(-2)K_n(2)}{I_2(-2)K_1(2)-I_1(-2)K_2(2)}\\
&=2\left(I_n(-2)K_1(2)+I_1(2)K_n(2)\right)\\
&=2\left((-1)^n I_n(2)K_1(2)+I_1(2)K_n(2)\right)\\
\\
B_n&=\frac{I_n(-2)K_0(2)-I_0(-2)K_n(2)}{I_1(-2)K_0(2)-I_0(-2)K_1(2)}\\
&=2\left(-I_n(-2)K_0(2)+I_0(2)K_n(2)\right)\\
&=2\left((-1)^{n-1} I_n(2)K_0(2)+I_0(2)K_n(2)\right)\\
\end{align}
(there was a sign error in MathWorld in the above expression, see too OEIS entries [A001053](https://oeis.org/A001053) and [A001040](https://oeis.org/A001040))

This means that we have (needing the $N+1$-th convergent for the $N$ at the end) :
$$[0;1,2,\dotsc,N]=\frac{A_{N+1}}{B_{N+1}}$$

From this we may get the next convergent using [Lord_Farin's helpful link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems) :

$$[0;1,2,\dotsc,N,x]=\frac{xA_{N+1}+A_{N}}{xB_{N+1}+B_{N}}$$

To get your continued fraction you only need to revert this and subtract $1$ obtaining :
$$[0;2,\dotsc,N,x]=\frac{xB_{N+1}+B_{N}}{xA_{N+1}+A_{N}}-1$$

Allowing the computation of :
\begin{align}
g(x,N)&=\int f(x,N)\;dx\\
&=\int \frac{xB_{N+1}+B_{N}}{xA_{N+1}+A_{N}}-1\;dx\\
&=\int \frac{B_{N}A_{N+1}-A_{N}B_{N+1}}{A_{N+1}(xA_{N+1}+A_{N})}+\frac {B_{N+1}}{A_{N+1}}-1\;dx\\
&=\frac{B_{N}A_{N+1}-A_{N}B_{N+1}}{A_{N+1}^2}\log(A_{N+1}\;x+A_{N})+\frac {B_{N+1}-A_{N+1}}{A_{N+1}}x\\
\\
g(x,N)&=\boxed{\displaystyle (-1)^{N+1}\frac{\log(A_{N+1}\;x+A_{N})}{A_{N+1}^2}+\frac {B_{N+1}-A_{N+1}}{A_{N+1}}x}\quad\text{(after simplification)}\\
\end{align}

I'll let you reverify all this,

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Lord_Farin !

Comment: To be complete let's add that the limit of my first continued fraction is well known as the [Euler-Gompertz constant](http://books.google.com/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA423) $\;c_1=\frac{I_1(2)}{I_0(2)}\;$ which was proved transcendental by Siegel.